# Can't receive Google Drive Android API's OnCompletionEvent for an upload

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to back up some files into a zip file and upload it to Google Drive using the Google Drive Android API (GDAA). Everything is working fine, up until the part where I should receive the CompletionEvent for the upload.
This is what I have so far...

**I create a DriveContents this way:**

```
Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGAPIClient)
                .setResultCallback...
```

**I use input/output streams to create a zip file of the files I want to upload. Then I create an ExecutionOptions object asking to be notified of the completion of the upload:**

```
ExecutionOptions executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions.Builder()
                                        .setNotifyOnCompletion(true)
                                        .build();
```

**Then I create the file in Google Drive's AppFolder this way (using the DriveContents and the ExecutionOptions created):**

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGAPIClient).createFile(mGAPIClient, metadataChangeSet, mDContents, executionOptions)
                                        .setResultCallback...
```

**This is my DriveEventService subclass, it should be responsible for receiving the CompletionEvent:**

```
public class MeuDriveEventService extends DriveEventService {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(CompletionEvent completionEvent) {
        super.onCompletion(completionEvent);
        Log.d("GAPI", "status do com.example.android.QsApp.MeuDriveEventService: " + completionEvent.getStatus());
        completionEvent.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**...and it is declared in my manifest:**

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.android.QsApp.MeuDriveEventService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.events.HANDLE_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The zip file *is* being created locally *and* uploaded successfully (I checked multiple times), I just don't get the CompletionEvent back. Am I missing a permission in my manifest or something? What am I overlooking here?

Comment: No logcat errors? The AppData folder is hard to look into. How do you know that the file is propagated to the Drive host?

Comment: No errors at all.
I can:
  1 - 'delete hidden data' in the AppData folder (through drive.google.com > settings > manage apps), run the code, check the size of the AppData folder (again through drive.google.com) and compare that size with the generated zip file in my device, or...

  2 - download the files in the AppData folder (programmatically) to my device and look inside that zip file (I did that later on).

I thought I was missing something obvious (I'm a beginner).

Comment: That's the way I would check. If you can put together a small app that demonstrates this problem (a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I would be willing to take a closer look. The code you posted looks OK.

Comment: I put together an MVCE and it worked. Now I'm stripping the original app down as much as I can so I can compare both and find out where's the bug. As soon as I have something, I'll post it back here. Thanks again, @Cheticamp.

Comment: @Cheticamp, I stripped down every part of the code I could, but it didn't work.
Checking the logcat, I see this line
`10-29 15:40:57.666 22848-23179/com.example.android.gdrive W/DriveEventService: Unhandled completion event: CompletionEvent [id=DriveId:CAESLDFYcHJIb2t6UUF2UG9vbGQwYy1uOFlGclhpUVJ0S1dDdHEyZUdpZ0l3elUwGOShASCct4-chVQoAA==, status=0, trackingTag='']`
when I run the MVCE, but not when I run the app. Does it mean anything useful?

Comment: You see that error on the MCVE or your app? The error looks like it can lead to the problem area. Post the MCVE if that's where the error is.

Comment: @Cheticamp That warrning is for the MCVE, which **is** working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I decided to **rebuild the project, reboot my devices, recreate the credentials at console.developers.google.com, wait for 30 minutes and give it another shot**. This time it worked (even though I have no idea why).

I'll leave this here in case someone else experiences this. Once again, thanks to @Cheticamp for helping a beginner like me.